# mySQL loses connection on one table, doesn't on any others

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with multiple tables. When I run a simple SELECT command on one of the tables, it gives the "lost connection" error, but when I run the same command on any of the other tables, it works just fine. Does anyone know what could be the cause of this issue? I'm running the commands from the MySQL Workbench.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: run `check table` on that table and see what you get

Answer (score 2):

Quite likely there is some sort of a transaction running. Whether you started the transaction via a sql command (i.e. START TRANSACTION) or whether some other query (possibly from a GUI) started a transaction (Like an ALTER TABLE command when adding a column) and the transaction never finished.

Run the command

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

to find the IDs of all processes that are running for your user

You can then kill the processes by running the command

```
KILL <PROCESS ID> (i.e. KILL 40196;)
```

When you find and stop the process that contained the transaction that never finished you will likely be able to query the table again. Your table will be queryable again, and you can look further into solving the problem of why the transaction was started but never finished.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the 'Interactive_timeout' and 'wait_timeout' properties in the mysql configuration file to the values ​​you need.